# How to mint mint NFT with StateMachine

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, native-assets, statemachines

I would like to mint an NFT in a particular state of the [state machine](https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-contract/html/Plutus-Contract-StateMachine.html)

Does anyone know where I can find some examples?

Answer (score 1):

There's a very complete example on how to mint NFTs [here](https://github.com/lambdacc/plutus-use-cases-mlabs/blob/main/mlabs/src/Mlabs/NFT/Contract/Mint.hs).

You can try to add this in the `transition` part of [this state machine](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program/blob/main/code/week07/src/Week07/StateMachine.hs).